# Joint result set

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that returns a results set now I need to amend the query to return another results set as well

I have run the code below and it returns results where the tagID's are in both CTE's and gives you the time in and time out. 
I need to amend the query now so it will show me all the tags that have also been scanned in with Time in and no out time and vice versa, without giving duplicates.

```
With CTE AS
( 
select Tag as 'Tag ID', UID_KEG, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), MOVEMENT_DATE, 105) 
as [DATE],CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), MOVEMENT_DATE, 108) as [Time Out]
from MOVEMENT M
Inner join KEG K on K.UNIQUE_ID = M.UID_KEG
where Convert(varchar(10),MOVEMENT_DATE,120) = '2019-06-13' 
and UID_STATION = 4
and TAG <> 'NO TAG'
) ,
CTE2 AS
(select Tag as 'Tag ID', UID_KEG, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), MOVEMENT_DATE, 105) 
as [DATE],CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), MOVEMENT_DATE, 108) as [Time IN]
from MOVEMENT M
Inner join KEG K on K.UNIQUE_ID = M.UID_KEG
where Convert(varchar(10),MOVEMENT_DATE,120) = '2019-06-13'
and UID_STATION = 5
and TAG <> 'NO TAG'
)
Select CTE.[Tag ID], CTE.[DATE], [Time IN], [Time Out],DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 
[Time IN], [Time Out]) as [Time in Process]
from CTE
Inner Join CTE2 on CTE2.[Tag ID] = CTE.[Tag ID]
where Exists (Select CTE2.[Tag ID] 
       from CTE2
       where CTE2.[Tag ID] = CTE.[Tag ID] )
```

The query at the minute gives me the below results:

```
TAG ID                      DATE        Time_In     Time_Out    DIF
33154A36D00F46C000007144    6/13/2019   4:43:05 AM  6:25:27 AM  102
33154A36D00F46C00000464A    6/13/2019   4:43:47 AM  6:06:45 AM  83
33154A36D00F46C000006DFF    6/13/2019   4:46:22 AM  6:25:27 AM  99
33154A36D00F46C0000040A8    6/13/2019   4:54:23 AM  6:10:55 AM  76
33154A36D00F46C000002ECB    6/13/2019   4:55:59 AM  6:10:55 AM  75
33154A36D00F46C000002A2F    6/13/2019   5:03:18 AM  6:20:40 AM  77
33154A36D00F46C000000499    6/13/2019   5:34:35 AM  6:25:27 AM  51
33154A36D00F46C00000627C    6/13/2019   5:38:04 AM  6:25:27 AM  47
33154A36D00F46C000006F74    6/13/2019   5:38:06 AM  6:28:42 AM  50
```

I'm looking now for the below to be returned as well:

```
33154A36D00F46C000006F38    6/13/2019              6:28:42 AM   
33154A36D00F46C000006F62    6/13/2019              6:47:42 AM   
33154A36D00F46C000006F90    6/13/2019              7:47:12 AM
```

Comment: sql tag is meant for ISO/IEC standard SQL and your question relates solely to a specific DBMS (uses specific extensions/features) this seams to be SQL Server (MSSQL) as you are using brackets

Comment: Please include table structure and sample data for movement and Keg tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not simplify the query and just do one pass?

```
select 
    Tag as 'Tag ID'
    , UID_KEG
    , max(iif(UID_STATION=4,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), MOVEMENT_DATE, 105),null)) as [DATE]
    , max(iif(UID_STATION=4,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), MOVEMENT_DATE, 108),null)) as [Time Out]
    , max(iif(UID_STATION=5,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), MOVEMENT_DATE, 108),null)) as [Time IN]
from MOVEMENT M
Inner join KEG K on 
    K.UNIQUE_ID = M.UID_KEG
    AND Convert(varchar(10),MOVEMENT_DATE,120) = '2019-06-13' 
    and UID_STATION in (4,5)
    and TAG <> 'NO TAG'
group by 
    Tag 
    , UID_KEG
```

If you want to keep the cte's then first of all, since you are doing an inner join, you can lose this:

```
where Exists (Select CTE2.[Tag ID] 
       from CTE2
       where CTE2.[Tag ID] = CTE.[Tag ID] )
```

If you inner join on [Tag ID], you only get values in both tables

I would lose that where clause, and change it to an outer join, in this case you get all the tag ids, whether they are in or out, or perhaps a left outer join, if you want all tags with a in date, like this:

```
With CTE AS
( 
select Tag as 'Tag ID', UID_KEG, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), MOVEMENT_DATE, 105) 
as [DATE],CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), MOVEMENT_DATE, 108) as [Time Out]
from MOVEMENT M
Inner join KEG K on K.UNIQUE_ID = M.UID_KEG
where Convert(varchar(10),MOVEMENT_DATE,120) = '2019-06-13' 
and UID_STATION = 4
and TAG <> 'NO TAG'
) ,
CTE2 AS
(select Tag as 'Tag ID', UID_KEG, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), MOVEMENT_DATE, 105) 
as [DATE],CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), MOVEMENT_DATE, 108) as [Time IN]
from MOVEMENT M
Inner join KEG K on K.UNIQUE_ID = M.UID_KEG
where Convert(varchar(10),MOVEMENT_DATE,120) = '2019-06-13'
and UID_STATION = 5
and TAG <> 'NO TAG'
)
Select CTE.[Tag ID], CTE.[DATE], [Time IN], [Time Out],DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 
[Time IN], [Time Out]) as [Time in Process]
from CTE
LEFT Join CTE2 on CTE2.[Tag ID] = CTE.[Tag ID]
```

--- added in edit

If you want a detediff for your in and out times how about:

```
SELECT
  Tag AS 'Tag ID',
  UID_KEG,
  MAX(iif(UID_STATION = 4, CONVERT(varchar(10), MOVEMENT_DATE, 105), NULL)) AS [DATE],
  MAX(iif(UID_STATION = 4, CONVERT(varchar(10), MOVEMENT_DATE, 108), NULL)) AS [Time Out],
  MAX(iif(UID_STATION = 5, CONVERT(varchar(10), MOVEMENT_DATE, 108), NULL)) AS [Time IN],
  DATEDIFF(MINUTE,
    MAX(iif(UID_STATION = 4, MOVEMENT_DATE, NULL)),
    MAX(iif(UID_STATION = 5, MOVEMENT_DATE, NULL))) AS [Time Elapsed]
FROM MOVEMENT M
INNER JOIN KEG K
  ON K.UNIQUE_ID = M.UID_KEG
  AND CONVERT(varchar(10), MOVEMENT_DATE, 120) = '2019-06-13'
  AND UID_STATION IN (4, 5)
  AND TAG <> 'NO TAG'
GROUP BY Tag,
         UID_KEG
```

Comment: Hi, in the first example, is there any way to get the DateDiff in, I've tried but coming with error Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: I didn't mention it, but I woulddn't call it good practice to do the date formatting in your query. If you present the data in a tool or a web page, then let the end tool do the formatting. However, I guess you want the datediff between in and out? I'll edit my answer for a possible solution

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is make a 2nd CTE clause that selects what you describe, with the same field layout and NULLs in the fields that are not relevant.

Then to SELECT from both, you do a

```
 SELECT * FROM CTE_A 
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT * FROM CTE_B 
          WHERE CTE_B.tag NOT IN (SELECT CTE_A.tag FROM CTE_A)
```